# How to change text selection color in JTextPane when DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter is applied?

Tags: java, highlight, jtextpane

I have `JTextPane` object. I've added `DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter` highlighter  like this:

```
DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter high = new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(Color.GREEN);
try {
   jTextPane1.getHighlighter().addHighlight(0, 20, high);
} catch (BadLocationException ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now, I want to select (highlight) text with my mouse. When I do that, the green part of text does not highlights in blue. I would like that all the text would highlight in blue when i select it with my mouse. How could i solve this issue?

[image: Selection issue]

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `DefaultHighlighter` with extended one where override the method

To start from 0

```
public void paintLayeredHighlights(Graphics g, int p0, int p1,
                                   Shape viewBounds,
                                   JTextComponent editor, View view) {
    for (int counter = highlights.size() - 1; counter >= 0; counter--) {
        HighlightInfo tag = highlights.elementAt(counter);
        if (tag instanceof LayeredHighlightInfo) {
            LayeredHighlightInfo lhi = (LayeredHighlightInfo)tag;
            int start = lhi.getStartOffset();
            int end = lhi.getEndOffset();
            if ((p0 < start && p1 > start) ||
                (p0 >= start && p0 < end)) {
                lhi.paintLayeredHighlights(g, p0, p1, viewBounds,
                                           editor, view);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `HighlightInfo` class is described without access level modifier, so I can't use this class in my extended class.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you could try something like this:

```
UIManager.put("JTextPane.selectionBackground", new javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource(Color.YELLOW));
```

Do this before the creation of JTextPane.

Comment: sorry, it doesn't help